# Evaluating limit of $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln(x)$

Tags: calculus

**Problem.**

Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln(x)$$

I split the limit up in a product of $x$ and $\ln(x)$ and get $0 \cdot -\infty$ which sounds a bit shady...Can I simply say that this is obviously $0$ because $0 \cdot a = 0, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$...?

Comment: $-\infty\notin\Bbb R$.

Comment: Damn...I need some hints then

Comment: Ask a Frenchman ...

Comment: For some reason I only think of using l'hospital when I've got a fraction. But thanks for the laugh, heh

Comment: Exactly, l'Hospital it is...

Comment: Isn't there a function for using l'Hospital? I'm tired of writing $\frac{d}{dx}$ over both the numerator and the denominator every step.

Comment: @user3200098 THere is a way. One time calculate your limit but raise $x$ to the power $n$ and then to the Frenchman way. The limit is still zero. From now on, call this a Standard Limit. You will never have to calculate it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\ln(x) =\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}
$$

Comment: Does this mean that ∴ the limit is 0?

Comment: @AnonymousPi Do you know L'Hopital's?

Comment: Emmmm... no. I know what is a limit, and if you tell me the result of one is something, I understand, but I really don't have much experience calculating them.

Comment: @AnonymousPi [here's an explanation of L'Hôpital's rule](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx), if you're interested.  L'Hôpital's rule allows you to simplify the limit of an indeterminate fraction by taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator.  What I've done here is put the limit in the form of an indeterminate fraction, so that we could directly apply L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to think about it: let $x=e^{-t}$; then the limit becomes:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\;\; -t \, e^{-t}$$

Maybe that's clearer.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/694307), for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
x\lt1+x\le e^x\tag{1}
$$
If $u\gt0$, applying $(1)$ to $u/2$ and squaring gives
$$
u^2/4\lt e^u\tag{2}
$$
Multiplying $(2)$ by $\dfrac4{ue^u}$ yields
$$
0\lt\frac{u}{e^u}\lt\frac4u\tag{3}
$$
Thus, applying $(3)$ and the Squeeze Theorem,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\log(x)
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\log(x)e^{\log(x)}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}-ue^{-u}\\
&=-\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{e^u}\\[3pt]
&=0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\log x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log x}{\frac1x}\stackrel{l\,'H}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac1x}{-\frac1{x^2}}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $t=\frac{1}{x}$, then

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln(x)=\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log(\frac{1}{t})}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{-\log(t)}{t}=0.$$

Comment: _@DonAntonio_ Sorry, a typo. Thanks for pointing out.