# Showing that $e^x > 1+x$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

**Problem.**

Show that $$e^x > 1 + x , \ \ x \neq 0$$

**My attempt.**

Using Mean Value Theorem:
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$

$$\Rightarrow e^c = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$$
$$\Rightarrow xe^c = e^x -1$$
$$\Rightarrow x+1 = \frac{e^x}{e^c}$$

I'm not feeling very comfortable with these calculations...Am I on the right track? Can I even choose $e^o$ in my initial calculation as it says that $x \neq 0 $ ?

Comment: Depends on your definition of $e^x$.

Comment: Just use the fact that $e^c > 1$ (when $x > 0$; you'll need to consider $x < 0$ separately). [Before that: what is the fact you've used to write $f'(c)$ equal to that ratio? What is $c$?]

Comment: The second line equation in your aligned equations is wrong, check it.

Comment: Is the first line of your attempt an appeal to the Mean Value Theorem? This should be stated explicitly (with words and sentences). Don't just throw a bunch of equations at the reader and expect him to figure out for himself what the point of them is.

Comment: Henning, if the reader does not immediately realize that is the Mean Value Theorem, then the reader cannot answer my question. But I added it, since you asked.

Comment: @user3200098: If this is homework, then your task is to learn writing proofs in the style expected by mathematicians. That style does not accept writing just a series of equations and leaving it to the reader to figure out what the significance of your equations are. It is **your job** to explain what you're doing with the equation (with actual words and sentences), and attempts to wiggle out of that by insulting the reader will just earn you ridicule.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What is wrong with my 2nd equation? I am using x = 0 in the mean value theorem, but I'm not sure if I am allowed to do that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I didn't mean to insult anyone and I am sorry if you feel insulted. I retract my previous statement.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'm having a hard time considering x<0. Can you give a hint?

Comment: There's a problem that $e^0 \ngtr 1 + 0$.  You probably meant to say $e^x \ge 1 + x$.

Comment: @NovaDenizen: The problem says $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @user3200098: I have added an answer elaborating the proof for both $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Answer (score 2):

A geometric way to prove the inequality is to use the convexity of the function  $f=\exp$ (since its second derivative is $e^x\ge0$) then the line tangent at $x=0$ with equation:
$$y=f'(0)x+f(0)=x+1$$
is below the curve of the function hence
$$e^x> x+1,\quad x\ne0$$

Comment: Does convexity mean that it is ever increasing?

Comment: No but for a differentiable function $f$ the derivative $f'$ is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Assume $x>0$. By MVT, there is a $c \in (0,x)$ so that $e^c = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$. Then $e^x = xe^c + 1$. But since $c \in (0,x)$, we  have $e^c > 1$, and $e^x = xe^c + 1 > x+1$.

(1) Assume $x<0$. By MVT, there is a $c \in (x,0)$ so that $e^c = \frac{1-e^x}{-x}$. Then $e^x = xe^c + 1$. But since $c \in (x,0)$, we  have $0 < e^c < 1$, and $e^x = xe^c + 1 > x+1$ (since $x<0$).

Answer (score 2):

The Mean Value Theorem is a valid approach.  Here is another approach; hopefully, it will make you more comfortable to have two.

The integer version of [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), proven at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), is sufficient to prove that, for $n_0\gt\max(-x,1)$ and $x\ne0$, we have
$$
1+x\lt\left(1+\frac x{n_0}\right)^{n_0}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x
$$

Comment: Taking the limit the inequality $<$ becomes $\le$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Not really since $1+x\lt\left(1+\frac x{n_0}\right)^{n_0}\le\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ for $n_0\gt|x|$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I have made this more explicit in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

for $x>0$, $e^x>1$ so $$\int_0^b e^xdx>\int_0^b dx=b$$ $$e^b-1>b$$ $$e^b>b+1$$ for $x<0$, $e^x<1$ so $$\int_a^0 e^xdx<\int_a^0dx,a<0$$ $$1-e^a<-a$$ $$1+a<e^a$$ so for any non zero number $c, e^c>c+1$ seeing as $e^0=1$

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be solved using the Taylor Series of $e^x$, which is $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$. Note that if $x > 0$, each and every term in the series will be greater than $0$, and therefore $e^x > 1+x$.

Comment: Its also true for $x<0$. Your example is not a counterexample.

Comment: Even for $x < 0$, we have $e^x > 1 + x$. And Taylor series is overkill (unless the exponential function has not been defined that way).

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider 2 cases:

a) $x > 0$: Then $(e^x - 1)/x = e^c > 1$ for some $c > 0$ then the conclusion follows.

b) $x < 0$: Then we need to prove: $-x > 1 - e^x$ or $1 > \frac{(1 - e^x)}{(0 - x)}$. Apply MVT again we have $\text{RHS} = e^c$ for some $c \,\text{in}\, (x, 0)$ so $\text{RHS} = e^c < e^0 = 1$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: This is the only answer that is actually using my method...Can you put this in latex? It's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x) = e^x - x - 1$$

Therfore you have $$f'(x) = e^x-1 $$

If you have a look at $f'(x)$ you will see that it is always greater than $0$ for $x>0$ . The value of $f(0)=0$ . After that the function is monotonically increasing and will always be $>0$ . Therefore from the above we can conculde that for $x>0$ , $f(x)>0$ . Hence $e^x-x-1>0$ , $e^x>x+1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the exponential function.

Suppose $x > 0$. Then by the mean-value theorem, there exists some $c$, with $0 < c < x$, such that 
$$f'(c) = \dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}$$
$$e^c = \dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}.$$
As $c > 0$, we have $e^c > 1$, and therefore $\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} > 1$. Multiplying both sides by the positive number $x$ gives $e^x - 1 > x$.

---

Suppose $x < 0$. Then by the mean-value theorem, there exists some $c$, with $x < c < 0$, such that
$$f'(c) = \dfrac{f(0) - f(x)}{0 - x}$$
$$e^c = \dfrac{1 - e^x}{-x} = \dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}.$$

As $c < 0$, we have $e^c < 1$, and therefore $\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} < 1$. Multiplying both sides by the negative number $x$ reverses the inequality, giving $e^x - 1 > x$ again, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using the Mean Value Theorem is OK, but you made a mistake in the final line.  It would correctly read $x+{1\over e^c}={e^x\over e^c}$ instead of $x+1$ on the left hand side.  But you really should have stopped at the second line, $e^c={e^x-1\over x}$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$, and then reasoned as follows:

If $x\gt0$, then $c\gt0$.  In this case $(e^x-1)/x=e^c\gt1$, hence $e^x-1\gt x$, so that $e^x\gt1+x$.

If $x\lt0$, then $c\lt0$.  In this case $(e^x-1)/x=e^c\lt1$, hence (and here you have to remember than multiplying by a negative number *reverses* the direction of the inequality!) $e^x-1\gt x$, so that $e^x\gt1+x$.

Answer (score 0):

Enough to show that for $x> 0$ we have $(1-x) < e^{-x}$, or
$$(1-x) e^x < 1$$
But we have
$$(1-x)\cdot e^x = 1 + \sum_{n\ge 1} \left(\frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right) x^n < 1$$