# Prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}=1$ without derivatives

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

> Prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}=1$.

I currently know only one approach (using L'Hopital 's Rule and derivatives) as follows:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{\left(e^x-1\right)'}{x'}}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\left(e^x\right)}=e^0=1$$

Here I ask for other proofs than those, preferably neither using derivatives **in any way** nor using Taylor, etc.

For the purposes of this post, I define the exponential by any of the following limits:
$$e^x
=\lim_\limits{n\to +\infty}{\left( 1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n}=\lim_\limits{n\to +\infty}{\left[ \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\cdot x}\right] }=\left[ \lim_\limits{n\to +\infty}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\right] ^x.$$

Note: An approach for $\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+}{(x\ln x)}$ without using derivatives can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694307).

Comment: We need to know which hands to tie behind our backs? What definition of $e^x$ is permissible?

Comment: @RobArthan The following definition(s) is(are) (all) allowed:
$$e^x=\lim_\limits{n\to +\infty}{\left( 1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n}=\lim_\limits{n\to +\infty}{\left[ \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\cdot x}\right] }=\left[ \lim_\limits{n\to +\infty}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\right] ^x$$

I would prefer to avoid the following definition (Taylor):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: We are splitting hairs since $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ are two equivalent *definitions* of $e^x$. You may prove it by noticing that both terms are continuous solutions of the functional equation $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$ with $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I thought that the last definition (the sum one) was proved using Taylor expansion, wasn't it?

Comment: A definition is a definition, there is nothing to prove about it. I am just saying that, equivalently, we may take one or the other as the definition of $e^x$, so to avoid one or the other is of little interest.

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/541330/72031 which uses $e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (x/n))^{n}$.

Comment: Posts about the same limit:
[Proving that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/152605). 
In particular this one seems closely related: [Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} (e^x-1)/x$ without using L'Hôpital's rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070524/calculate-lim-x-to-0-ex-1-x-without-using-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can assume the "Important limit" $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+x)^{1/x}=e$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} &= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{\ln (1+y)}\\
&= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\ln \left((1+y)^{1/y}\right)}\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Using 
$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=1+x+O(x^2)$$ 
Which is not directly using the Taylor Series, just the binomial expansion.

You can procede like in the proof of using the Taylor series.

Answer (score 2):

Since $1 + x \le e^x$ for all $x$ and we have $e^x \le 1/(1 - x)$ for $x < 1$
so 
$$1 \le (e^x - 1)/x \le 1/(1 - x) \to 1$$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: While this is not in the question, the "admissible" definition(s) of the exponential is(are) given in comments.  Your definition is not among those "admissible" definitions.  Before proving the desired result, you should demonstrate that your definition is, indeed, equivalent to the "admissible" definition(s).

Comment: This definition implies the "admissible" definition. Note $1 - x \le e^{-x}$ so $e^x \le 1/(1 - x)$ for $x < 1$. Hence $(1 + x/n)^n \le e^x \le (1 - x/n)^{-n}$ Both sides converge to $\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n/n!$

Answer (score 1):

Using that

$$\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
and that the series
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$
is uniformly convergent on every interval containing $0$ so interchanging limit and $\sum$ is allowed and the result follows.

Comment: This uses the taylor expansion, which was supposed to be avoided.

Comment: The OP said "preferrably" avoiding Taylor.

Comment: -1: op asked not to use derivatives, taylor and related

Comment: @Blex: please see my comment below the main question. (+1) back.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: If $exp(x) = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$ by definition then I agree, but I'm denied un-(-1) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use the fact that $e^z$ is analytic and hence you can take $z=iy\rightarrow 0$ and obtain the same limit (assuming it exists) the  you get $\frac{\sin y}{y}$ whose limit can be obtained from geometrically.

Comment: I will delete my post as it's redundant now!!

Comment: I don't think it's redundant despite the similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of e, the limit becomes the same as:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}-1}{x}$$

We can evaluate this along the path $n=\frac{1}{x}$. So, the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{
\left(1+x\right)^{x/x}-1}{x}$$

This gives us:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{
\left(1+x\right)-1}{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

maybe this satisfies. 
$$
\frac{e^x-1}{x} = e^{x/2}\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{x} \to  e^{it}\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{i2t} = \frac{\sin t}{t}e^{it}
$$
Then taking limits to zero.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you proceed with the $\to$? Where did $2it$ appear? Sorry to bother you...