# How to show that the Shannon Entropy is well defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

The Shannon entropy $I(P)$ of a probability vector $P \in [0,1]^{n}$ is given by

$I(P) = - \sum_{\gamma = 1}^{n} P_{\gamma} ln(P_{\gamma})$

I want to show that $I(P)$ is well defined i.e., $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} xln(x) = 0$

Does someone have any idea how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694145/evaluating-limit-of-lim-x-to-0-x-lnx